# PropertyChanged with TemplateSelector and grouped List of objects in LongListSelector issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I am writing chat application for `windows phone 8` using `MVVM` pattern. My problem is to notify the `LongListSelector` where group of `ObservableCollection` items is changing.
Ok step by step:

The grouped contacts list is an object

`public ObservableCollection<Group<ContactModel>> GroupedContacts`

Where group is:

```
public class Group<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public Group(string name, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.Key = name;
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            this.Add(item);                
        }
    }

    public string Key
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then I am adding two kind of grups to that object:

```
private void CreateGroups()
{
    var group = new Group<ContactModel>("Online", new ObservableCollection<ContactModel>());
    GroupedContacts.Add(group);
    group = new Group<ContactModel>("Offline", new ObservableCollection<ContactModel>());
    GroupedContacts.Add(group);
}
```

After adding some `ContactModel` objects to each of groups I am binding it to my `LongListSelector` When property `Online` of `ContactModel` is changing I am moving that object from one group to another - that works without problem. Problem is my `TemplateSelector` is not changing the `ContentTemplate`.

TemplateSelector:

```
public class AvailabilityTemplateSelector : ContentControl
{
    public DataTemplate OnlineTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate OfflineTemplate { get; set; }
    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);
        var contact = newContent as ContactModel;
        if (contact.Online)
        {
            ContentTemplate = OnlineTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            ContentTemplate = OfflineTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem here is where I am moving the object from one group to another. The `GroupedContacts` property is not notyfing that property has changed. The `ObservableCollection` that is in property `GroupedContacts` does it but it's not the `Content` of my `LongListSelector`. Any idea how to "tell" from `ObservableCollection` to my `GroupedContacts` property that changes were set and then from `GroupedContacts` to my `LongListSelector`

Comment: After some debuging I've discovered that notyfing is working well, problem is in another place. The other content item is going to TemplateSelector, not the one that has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a `Converter` instead of `TemplateSelector` and everything is working fine at this moment. I needed to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to my `ContactModel` class to make sure that changes to layout will be "live".

Answer (score 0):

There is everything wrong in your example.

Your ContentControl knows about your model. Thats a no go in WPF!

Bty if you want to listen to content changes you should NOT write a custom control but instead you should user DataTemplateSelector.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I cant use that becouse it is not accessible on Windows Phone platform.

Comment: Actually as I wrote before I am trying to understand why different content is getting to OnContentChanged method, not the ContactModel that actually got changed.

Comment: What different content? There such a thing for phones too.

Comment: You mean something like that: [link](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/08/06/multiple-item-templates-in-windows-phone.aspx) ? It is not working too. By content I mean: lets say one of my contacts in LongListSelector changed then OnContentChanged method will be invoked few times for different contacts (no idea why) but not for the contact that actually changed.

Comment: Yes I mean public class ContactTemplateSelector : TemplateSelector